# Protected constructor for :where new() constraint

Tags: c#

I wrote a class using Decoration Pattern to avoid inheritance issues.
And I made Factory Method to enforce component to copy its instance.
The code would be like this:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }

    public Foo() { }
}

public abstract class FooDecorator : IFoo
{
    protected IFoo _Foo;
    
    public int Bar
    {
        get
        {
            return _Foo.Bar;
        }
        set
        {
            _Foo.Bar = value;
        }
    }

    public static TOutput Create<TOutput, TInput>(TInput foo)
            where TOutput : FooDecorator, new()
            where TInput : IFoo, new()
    {
        var copy = new TInput
        {
            Bar = foo.Bar
        };
        return new TOutput { _Foo = copy };
        }
    }
}

public class FooDecoratorImpl : FooDecorator
{
    public FooDecoratorImpl() {} // This is necessary only for new() constraint. I'd like to hide it.

    public static FooDecoratorImpl Create<T>(T foo) where T : IFoo, new()
    {
        return Create<FooDecoratorImpl, T>(foo);
    }
}

Foo foo = new Foo() { Bar = 1 };

FooDecoratorImpl decorator = FooDecoratorImpl.Create(foo);
Console.WriteLine(decorator.Bar) // show "1"

FooDecoratorImpl unintended = new FooDecoratorImpl(); // I don't like to do this!
```

Since the default constructor is read only on the `FooDecorator.Create(foo)` method, I'd like its access modifier set to `protected` (I knew this doesn't work because `FooDecorator` isn't `FooDecoratorImpl`'s derived type, but the other way round.) to prevent unintended instantiation.
But the constructor needs to be public.
How can I restrict the constructor to be loaded on `FooDecorator.Create(foo)` only?

Comment: Why do you need the `new()` constraint?

Comment: Because both `TInput` and `TOutput` needs to instanciate inside the `Create` method.

Comment: [Quote from the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) *"The `new` constraint specifies that a type argument in a generic class declaration must have a **public** parameterless constructor."* This cannot be done with constraints. You can pass a factory function maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use generic classes with regular constructors:

```
public abstract class FooDecorator<TSource> : IFoo
    where TSource : IFoo, new()
{
    protected IFoo _Foo;
    
    public int Bar
    {
        get
        {
            return _Foo.Bar;
        }
        set
        {
            _Foo.Bar = value;
        }
    }

    protected FooDecorator(TSource foo)
    {
        // TODO: null check foo
        var copy = new TSource
        {
            Bar = foo.Bar
        };

        _Foo = copy;
    }
}

public class FooDecoratorImpl<TSource> : FooDecorator<TSource>
    where TSource : IFoo, new()
{
    public FooDecoratorImpl(TSource foo)
        : base(foo)
    {
    }
}

Foo foo = new Foo() { Bar = 1 };

var decorator = new FooDecoratorImpl<Foo>(foo);
Console.WriteLine(decorator.Bar) // show "1"

// this won't compile
var unintended = new FooDecoratorImpl<Foo>();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This ends my headache. Only thing I don't like is you mast decrare component's type inside angle blacket, but this even solves depending on the factory method. Inheriting `ICloneable` on `IFoo` might be another improvement.